# Eclipselink prevents uncached query results from being garbage collected

Tags: java, jpa, garbage-collection, eclipselink

## Situation

In my application I'm using Eclipselink v2.5.2 as the JPA provider. Running in Weblogic v12.1.3 and Java 8.

Every night a large task is due and my application queries the database for a full days worth of data (around 200 MB in Java Objects), 
this data should not be cached by JPA. All involved entities have the `@Cacheable(false)` annotation.
In order to process this data some configuration is also taken from the database, these entities and query results should be cached by eclipselink. 
With an expiration of 1 minute and the cacheType SOFT_WEAK. Meaning that caches can be cleared relatively quicly when memory is low. The shared cached mode in Eclipselink is globally set to `DISABLE_SELECTIVE`

The large task is execute by a stateless EJB, the data and configuration are retrieved from the database in one transaction, but collected by different 
stateless EJBs, who have their own `EntityManager` injected by Weblogic (using the same `@PersistenceContext`).

The caching works as expected with respect to speed and queries executed against the database.

## Problem

However when looking at the memory usage of the application further, 
I have noticed that after the daily task the amount of memory used is about 200mb higher, and by forcing this task to run several times in a row (taking well over 1 minute), 
I can get the application to run out of memory (and eventually throw an `OutOfMemoryError`).

After noticing this, I have inspected a heapdump (see screenshot), and confirmed that Eclipselink is preventing the large data set from being collected by the Garbage Collector.
I interpret this heapdump as follows (added in red are my conclusions from using the Eclipse Memory Analysis, 'inspect' window):

1. This data is kept in the 'queryResults' attribute of the IdentityMapManager (on line 3)
2. In this cache is one of my objects (a cached JPA Entity, that is used as a parameter in a cached query).
3. In this entity is a reference to RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork, which I can not find in the 'inspect' window as an attribute of my Entity.
4. This eventually references another IdentityMapManager
5. The data of my large query is held here, under the 'identityMaps' attribute of the IdentityMapManager.

[image]

In my example I have run the large task 3 times which will result in 3x the same data (both the large set and the configuration). Eclipselink keeps a full copy of each run alive.

## Possible work around

I have found that calling `entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();` will clean up this data. I suspect that clearing the cache for just the query involved here will do the same.

## Question

I would like to know why Eclipselink keeps the large dataset around. Is there something I am doing wrong, or is this a bug in Eclipselink?

Also I would like to know when Eclipselink will clean up this data, is that when my 'initial size' is reached for the query, or is it cleared sooner?

## Edits

- The entity that is used as the parameter in a cached query, contains a lazily loaded list. ([this post](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists//eclipselink-users/msg08403.html) hints that might cause it's context to be kept alive)

Comment: Sounds like both a bug and an issue with your configuration/query that is causing entities read in from an EntityManager to be referenced in the shared cache.  This shouldn't happen; EntityManagers will have hard references to all entities read through them as it is required to manage their state, and for change tracking and lazy fetching purposes, those entities have links to the EntityManager used to read them.  If they get in the shared cache, it prevents the EM and all referenced entities from  being GCd. You'll need to further track down the entity in the shared cache and how it got there

Comment: Check that you are not changing 'read-only' entities somehow, as these changes are made directly to the shared cache.

Comment: @Chris I don't have any entities or queries marked as read only explicitly (so there should not be any?). The entity is in the cache because it is used as a parameter in a cached query, and the entity indeed contains a lazygfetched list of other elements. I have now noticed that eventually these objects do get cleaned up, but I am not sure what triggers this (this same query that is holding the objects in its cache is only done once a day, so it is not that).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by the entity is used as a parameter in a cached query.  The shared cache is referencing something that has a reference to an EntityManager context, so it was read from an EM and got stuffed in the EMF somehow.  You need to determine how it got in the shared cache so this can be prevented.  You can clear the EMF cache, but then you lose the entire cache. As for read-only: This can be a query hint, a descriptor or even persistence property setting.  You might be better off tracking the object in the shared cache to where it was loaded if possible.